# How to disable pidgin notifications? Pidgin + facebook has too many notifications for friends coming online

Tags: notification, empathy, pidgin, facebook

I logged into facebook messenger on Pidgin. Now for about an hour afterwords I get endless notifications of people coming "online" on facebook. I can't find any option to disable this, but it's a real nuisance. They are the built in "Unity" ubuntu notifications. "John Smith is Online" it says over and over and over again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go into the pidgin main window and open the tools menu, add-ons and a new window opens showing the add-ons.

Search for the lib.notify entry and there you can disable to show logins/logouts.

It is not recommended to disable the plugin itself, at least if you do not care about the message indicator integration.